# Why I am getting Facebook login pop up for every site?

Tags: chrome, facebook, safe-browsing-filter

My Chrome browser keeps prompting me for Facebook authentication, even though I have never logged on to Facebook from my PC.

I am using Chrome browser from my company where they have a strong proxy to avoid social networking sites. Though, I never even tried to open Facebook or any application/site related to FB. But I am constantly getting this pop up when ever I open any site. Is that a security threat?

[image]

*Edit*

I am sorry but I don't have any knowledge about proxy server configuration. However, I can tel you about configuration of proxy account:

[image]

Well there are two scenarios, by default *Automatically detect setting* is enabled which doesn't allow us to access anything other than intranet site. However, when I am connected to VPN then I am able to use another proxy which allow me to access Google & other technical sites. (I can access Gmail, SO, Blogs but not Facebook)

Comment: And only http? Big red flag for me

Comment: @S.L.Barth: connect.facebook.net is the facebook SDK used in the like buttons, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button.

Comment: Please add information about your network configuration. The main question is if you have setup the company proxy explicitly in your browser or if you use it as a transparent proxy (i.e. no special setup in the browser). Apart from that it would be useful to know if there is any company internal documentation on how you should actually setup the browser in their network and if you've followed this documentation.

Comment: @S.L.Barth : `whois facebook.net` : Registrant Organization: Facebook, Inc.  1601 Willow Road, Menlo Park CA. So it is Facebook's URL

Comment: From the edited question it can be seen that some sort of proxy configuration with a PAC file is used. But the contents of the PAC file is unknown and thus it is impossible to see if the site in question is accessed by an explicit proxy or by a transparent proxy. And of course the configuration of the proxy is unknown and probably only known to the site administrators. My guess is still that it is some (popular) BlueCoat ProxySG or similar which is explicitly configured to behave that way.

Comment: As @Steffen said, it's impossible to determine whether it's transparent or explicit proxy. Either ways, and as a security administrator, I recommend to check it with your network admins, and remember, there is no login Facebook pop up like that, so be more careful!

Comment: I agree with @Emadeddin that you should check with your administrators because these are the ones which should really know whats going on.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

TL;TR: it is probably a BlueCoat ProxySG or similar proxy which can be configured to behave that way. Nothing to worry about.

Details:

What you see is a dialog for [HTTP basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). This is not what Facebook uses for authentication. This means that this dialog is not from Facebook itself.

My guess is that facebook.com is filtered by your "strong proxy to avoid social networking sites" but that access to this site is allowed for some authorized users. Thus what you see here is the authentication requested by the proxy you use. Usually proxy authentication is different from site authentication and it would show you that the proxy and not facebook requires authentication. But some software/appliances can be configured to issue a site authentication when used as a transparent proxy, i.e. when not being explicitly configured as proxy inside the browser.

One such proxy software is BlueCoat ProxySG. From [their documentation](https://bto.bluecoat.com/webguides/proxysg/6.5/authentication_webguide/Content/Topics/Authentication/Concepts/auth_modes_co.htm) it can be seen that it will return a site authentication (code 401) instead of proxy authentication (code 407) when used as transparent proxy:

> The ProxySG appliance issues an OCS-style challenge (**HTTP 401**) for the first connection request from an unauthenticated client.

This leaves the question why you get this authentication request everywhere. My guess is that you don't get the dialog everywhere but on all sites which embed the Facebook Like button, which is almost everywhere.  The site connect.facebook.net you see in the dialog is the Facebook SDK for the Like button.

Comment: One way to get rid of the facebook buttons (and thus the dialog) is using an adblocker with an appropriate filter list. (For example ublock origin list a few "Social" blocklists)

Answer (score 37):

This is a **proxy authentication** pop up! And it's most likely a proxy related attack.

When you connect to the Internet through a proxy, you'll be asked to enter username and password if the proxy requires an authentication.

For example:

[image: auth dialog]

Note that the whole text `The server http:// ... The server says` is editable, and you can change it in the proxy server settings.

Steps of fake proxy attack:

- Setting up a proxy with basic authentication 'no hashing on client side'
- Performing DNS poisoning, so every request will be redirected to the proxy machine
- ARP spoofing, so the attacker can take 'the DNS' place

After applying the attack, the following scenario happens when you open any site:

1. HTTP request for your site, assume it's: http://www.foo.com
2. The request will go to the fake proxy machine, so the proxy will reply with `407 authentication required` no matter what your request is. And send back the server message with the reply.
3. A pop up will show, displaying the server message.
4. So, if you enter your info, it will go to the fake proxy, then you might be redirected to the Internet.

So, check the DNS response you're getting for any website using Wireshark. It's probably from a suspicious address, the one that achieving DNS spoofing on your network.

Comment: I find it unlikely that this is an attack because this login does look totally different from the login someone is used to get from Facebook. If this would be a malicious proxy it would be much more convincing to mirror the design of the original login page. I'd rather suspect that this is a non-malicious proxy with access restrictions, like I proposed in my response.

Comment: You didn't get what I meant, the pop up is for access authentication regardless of the requested page. It has nothing to do with Facebook. the attacker is using the phrase `connect.facebook.net` like it's kind of Social Engineering method. 
As I said, check it using Wireshark, and be sure to see the `407 auth required ` message, it should be right after your http request.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is no attacker and no other kind of malicious activity. It is just the "strong proxy to avoid social networking sites" they have installed in the company network which is working as intended, i.e. restricting access to social networks.

Comment: How do you connect to your proxy ? Please list all of your browser network settings.

Comment: I don't know how the OP is connecting to the proxy but there are basically two ways: configure it as explicit proxy in the browser or use it as an implicit (transparent) proxy. Proxy authentication works only properly if using an explicit proxy so my guess is that the OP did not configure an explicit proxy and this way the required proxy authentication will be interpreted as authentication required by the target site.

Comment: @nocomprende:  In my opinion it is simply a misconfiguration of the client which then causes these unexpected authentication requests. This means it is not an attack which also explains why there is no attacker. If this would really be an attack  it must be a dumb attacker which cannot even give a proper looking facebook login page to better fool its victim. Unfortunately the OP is silent about how its browser is configured in regard to the company proxy.

Comment: @nocomprende: its probably futile to argue  since you seem to be convinced that it must be an attack and will interpret every argument in this direction. It is true that this behavior can be caused by an attack but it is also true that it can be caused by a misconfiguration of the proxy in the browser. And I find misconfiguration more likely. But without getting more information from the OP the question can not be ultimately answered.

Comment: It's most likely a proxy configuration issue, not an attack.

Comment: A misconfiguration issue will not display `http://connect.facebook.net` before you even request a website.

Comment: It is probably a Bluecoat ProxySG used as a transparent proxy. In this mode they return site authentication (code 401) because proxy authentication (code 407) will not work. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich & Emadeddin  I have updated my question with more information. I am sorry but I have very little knowledge about computer security and due to these answers I am able to get basic understand about proxy settings. please check my edit if that help.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Remember that there are people in this world that actually fall for 'Nigerian Prince' scams. Those sort of people (who also tend to not be very 'computer-literate') are the sort of people who wouldn't think twice about the login looking different.

Comment: @Pharap: Again: it can be explained with being an attack but it can be explained with not  being an attack. And some like to see attacks everywhere even if it can be explained otherwise. https://xkcd.com/1180/.